Does the Feller-Tornier constant equal this limit of a sum involving the $\Omega$ function?
I read this question about the Feller-Tornier constant $C_{\textrm{FT}}$, and have a further question as to a claimed definition of it.
According to Wikipedia,
$$C_{\textrm{FT}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} ([\Omega(k)\equiv0\mod 2])}{n}.$$
This definition is the limiting density of a different set from the set in Wikipedia's first definition. And that second set's limiting density appears to be $1/2$, or, if not, only a hair less. Certainly not $C_{\textrm{FT}}\approx 0.661$. Have I missed something? Is there actually a valid second definition of $C_{\textrm{FT}}$ in terms of $\Omega$, but the above formula in Wikipedia has a typo? Or is $\Omega$ irrelevant?
Wikipedia's first definition accords with Wolfram.
